# NPM ERR! When trying to run Meteor project

Tags: node.js, meteor

I'm trying to view someone else's Meteor project from Github. I cloned it then tried running it by typing 'meteor' but what results is this slew of errors. I've included a sample below. I am running the command prompt as administrator. Clearly this has something to do with Node or its packages but I'm at a loss of where I should go with this. If someone could give me a hint I would be grateful.

> npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/camelcase
> npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/map-obj
> npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-db
> npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/get-stdin
> npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/repeating
> npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
>
> etc. etc....
>
> npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 50,
> npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EPERM',
> npm ERR! error rolling back   path:
> 'C:\Users\Kyle\Documents\Websites...
>
> npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)' ] }
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
>
> npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
> npm ERR! command
> "C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.10\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\bin\\node.exe"
>
> "C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.10\mt-
> os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
> "install"
> npm ERR! cwd
> C:\Users\Kyle\Documents\Websites\thisWebsite\packages\npm-container.npm\package-new-14v2dj3
>
> npm ERR! fstream_type File
> npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
> npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chmod
> npm ERR! code ENOENT
> npm ERR! errno 34
> npm ERR! fstream_stack
> C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.10\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\bin\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:305:19
>
> npm ERR! fstream_type Directory    npm
> ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
> npm ERR! code EPERM
> npm ERR! errno 50
> npm ERR! stack Error:
> EPERM, mkdir
>
> npm ERR! node -v v0.10.40
> npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
> npm ERR! path...
>
> npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
> npm ERR!
> Error: version not found: ansi-styles@2.2.0
> npm ERR!     at
> C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.10...
>
> npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
> npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
> npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
> npm ERR! http://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
> npm ERR! command
> "C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.10\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\bin\\node.exe"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked in my particular case:

1. Remove meteorhacks and npm-container by typing this in the console:

> meteor remove meteorhacks:npm npm-container

2. Delete the 'npm-container' folder which is generated by the package.
3. Run 'npm init' to create a package.json
4. Copy the contents of packages.json to the dependencies section of package.json

Answer (score 1):

Try running the CMD / Powershell with Administrator (Run as Administrator). and then install npm dependencies as Github usually don't store them do: `npm install` and `npm start`. If you keep getting the errors. go to `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\`
 or where your nodejs is installed and do right click, choose 'Properties' and go to 'Security' tab and  give privileges to the user you need and try running npm install. Good luck

Comment: I tried all of the above and the problem remains. I'm pretty sure this project uses the Meteorhacks NPM so there is a packages.json rather than package.json in the root. I can't run npm install without a package.json in the root--though I did an 'npm init' anyways to see if it would work. The error messages come about while 'building package npm-container' during the build process, which is the meteorhacks package.

Comment: Yeah, that gives me the same list of NPM ERR! messages. Then I tried removing meteorhacks and npm-container, deleting the npm-container folder, and moving the contents of packages.json to the dependencies of package.json after doing 'npm init'. That got me further but it gave me this error instead, "Error: FS.Store.S3 you must specify the "bucket" option". Seems like a whole different issue now.

Comment: ...which was solved by typing 'meteor --settings settings.json'. I'll create my previous comment as an answer just in case others stumble upon this.