# Meteor not working on a git clone

Tags: node.js, windows, mongodb, meteor

I was planning to work on the project of a friend by cloning his project from BitBucket on my computer and then using meteor to work on it, sadly meteor is not starting correctly:

First, the proxy and MongoDB didn't started, so I search and solved it apparently by adding : `54.192.225.217 warehouse.meteor.com` to `etc/hosts`.
It worked for a while, meteor downloaded a lot of things until I got this error:

```
C:\Dev\project>meteor
[[[[[ C:\Dev\project ]]]]]
**=> Started proxy.**
**=> Started MongoDB.**
..\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:165
      throw error;
      ^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '..\Local\Temp\mt-14qz4yr\os\packages\cfs_collection-filters.js'
    at Error (native)

C:\Dev\project>
```

I'm on Windows 10, use METEOR 1.4.1.2 *(which works fine on another project)*, Smart Git & Bitbucket.

`meteor npm rebuild` gave:

```
"rebuild"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! phantomjs@2.1.7 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the phantomjs@2.1.7 install script 'node install.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the phantomjs package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
```

Comment: You might try downgrading to meteor 1.4.1.1 - A friend had a similar problem on Windows

Comment: Once you download the copy of the code on to your local machine, try a ```meteor reset``` and then start the app. If it still is giving you issues, try to update the app to the latest available version like @Mikkel has suggested using ```meteor update``` Also, see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38162318/npm-err-when-trying-to-run-meteor-project?rq=1) answer is helpful for your case